# Manipulating jQuery to get an error: "jQuery requires a window and a document"

Tags: javascript, jquery

If anyone flicked through the uncompressed version of jQuery, one may encounter something like:

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {

        // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
        // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
        // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
        // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
        // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
        // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
        // See ticket #14549 for more info.
        module.exports = global.document ?
            factory( global, true ) :
            function( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            };
    } else {
        factory( global );
    }
```

Notice the `throw new Error()` part. If I am not mistaken, it only throws the error if a window and document are not present. I am aware that things like Node.js could trigger this error, but can a normal HTML, CSS and JS web page trigger this in any way?

Comment: I don't think so. I think that's the whole point -- it works in browsers.

Comment: I'm sure there's a clever way of manipulating the browser's JavaScript environment to make jQuery think it's running in an environment with a global object without a `document` property. It would take a lot of work and likely a few browser warning dialogs. To what end? So an error shows up in the console? Booooring. :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I get what you mean, but playing with JS and turning things that are so popular and usually work so well into something that you manage to force to make a mistake, is kind of fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Node.js will not throw an error here since it contains a global object with a "document" inside it; you can use jquery with Node.js.
2. You'd be better off using [CherrioJS](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), which is designed specifically to be "like jQuery but for the server.
3. Attempts to use jQuery with "[ElectronJS](https://www.electronjs.org/)" or "[Headless Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md)" are examples where this error will throw.

Comment: Pretty sure Headless Chrome runs jQuery just fine; it's the basis for Puppeteer after all.

Comment: This looks promising, except for one thing, I'm not familiar with "CherrioJS", "Headless Chrome" or "ElectronJS". (Though, I think I may have heard about Electron.) So the question is, are those three (except maybe Headless Chrome because of what I heard in the comments here) all libraries you use in any kind of HTML, CSS and JS web page or something like NodeJS which is more to do with the server side?